# Highlight table row when check box is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jquery-selectors

Need to highlight the entire row when check box is checked and remove highlight when unchecked. My current code highlights just the check box cell not the entire row. HElp!

JSP:

```
 <tbody>
<c:forEach items="${summary}" var="summary">

<tr>
<td bgcolor='<c:out value="${summary.color}"></c:out>'><c:out
                    value="${summary.eventDesc}" />
</td>
 <td bgcolor='<c:out value="${summary.color}"></c:out>'><a
                href="/analysis/loadAnalysisDetailFromSummary?labelNbr=${summary.labelNbr}&loadDate=${summary.loadDate}"><c:out
                        value="${summary.labelNbr}" /> </a>
            </td>

        <td bgcolor='<c:out value="${summary.color}"></c:out>'><c:out
                    value="${summary.origin}" />
            </td>
        <td bgcolor='<c:out value="${summary.color}"></c:out>'><c:out
                    value="${summary.senderName}" />
            </td>
        <td bgcolor='<c:out value="${summary.color}"></c:out>'><c:out
                    value="${summary.receiverName}" />
            </td>
        <td bgcolor='<c:out value="${summary.color}"></c:out>'><c:out
                    value="${summary.receiptDate}" />
            </td>
        <td bgcolor='<c:out value="${summary.color}"></c:out>'><c:out
                    value="${summary.loadDate}" />
            </td>
        <td bgcolor='<c:out value="${summary.color}"></c:out>'><c:out
                    value="${summary.forecastIsc}" />
            </td>
        <td bgcolor='<c:out value="${summary.color}"></c:out>'><c:out
                    value="${summary.actualIsc}" />
            </td>
        <td bgcolor='<c:out value="${summary.color}"></c:out>'><c:out
                    value="${summary.country}" />
            </td>
    <td id="td1" bgcolor='<c:out value="${summary.color}"></c:out>'><c:out
                    value="${summary.source}" />
            </td>
<c:if test="${isAll == 'false'}">
    <td align='center' bgcolor='<c:out value="${summary.color}"></c:out>'>
    <input name='summaryCheckbox' type="checkbox" class="cbx" 
 value='<c:out value="${summary.labelNbr}"></c:out>,<c:out   
  value="${summary.loadDate}"></c:out>,
      <c:out value="${summary.eventInd}"></c:out>'>
            </td>
            </c:if>
        </tr>

    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(e) {
    if($(this).is(":checked")){ 
   $(this).closest('td').addClass("highlight");

  }
    else{
      $(this).closest('td').removeClass("highlight");
    }
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
table{border: 1px solid;}
.highlight{background: #C0C0C0;}
```

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML, not whatever that is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that when you switch it from  `closest("td")` to `closest("tr")` it is working [it sets the class], but the CSS is wrong. You need to add the background color to the cell, not the row.

Your CSS

```
table{border: 1px solid;} 
.highlight{background: #C0C0C0;}
```

Needs to be

```
table{border: 1px solid;} 
.highlight td {background: #C0C0C0;}
```

Notice the TD after highlight.

Answer (score 8):

```
$(function(){
    $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass("highlight", this.checked);
    });
});
```

Comment: I would do it:
`$("table tbody").on('change', "input[type='checkbox']", function() {` so it attaches to one element, not to every cb.

Comment: @epascarello - does it really matter for a few elements, or for 20 elements, or even more? Delegation has costs as well, checking every change event in the table to see if it originates from a checkbox or not.

Comment: Thanks! Ive tried using .closest('tr') but it didnt work thats why I posted this question. I also tried using parents() but that didnt work either.

Answer (score 5):

use `.closest('tr')`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(e) {
    if($(this).is(":checked")){ 
      $(this).closest('tr').addClass("highlight");
    }else{
      $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("highlight");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Ive tried using .closest('tr')   but it didnt work thats why I posted this question. I also tried using parents() but that didnt work either.